# Audio Chat + Data Stream Library for iOS

Tags: ios, sdk, streaming, audio-streaming

I want to build an iOS app that streams audio and some additional custom data between two users real-time. This is possible using GameKit if people are on the same network, but I haven't been able to find an SDK that can do this across the world.

Does anyone know if there is an existing service that does this?

If not, what services do you recommend for doing these two things (streaming audio and streaming data) separately?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into it, it seems that QuickBlox is able to do everything I need.

Answer (score 1):

WebRTC (www.webrtc.org/) has support for iOS (for audio streams, video promised later). But anyway in order to support communication for peers behind NATs - you will need your own sans, stun servers...

Comment: Isn't WebRTC more built around the browser? This is more of a real native app streaming data to another app. Think Skype but not sending video data.

Comment: Actualy it is available for Android (http://www.webrtc.org/reference/getting-started) and very soon will be available for iOS (as I  heard it on a conference about WebRTC from guys using it in Viber application)

Comment: Interesting. I'm looking into QuickBlox. Hopefully that does what I need. I'll report if I get it to work.